# Why does this code result in these answers?

Tags: java, math, methods

I am currently learning Java, and I'm trying to understand the logic behind math in Java. On old tests in this course, there have been problems like the ones below. I am then supposed to write out what this code is going to display. My problem is that I don't understand two of the numbers in both codes.

In the first test class, the integer Tal prints out as 15. Ok, I can follow the logic there.

It goes like this:

```
c.setNbrOf(4+1) = 5
int tal = c.getNbrOf()+10 = 15
```

BUT

When I apply the same logic to the second test class I get the wrong answer.
My logic goes:

```
c.setNbrOf(4+1) = 5
c2.setNbrOf(5) +1 = 6
```

Since Customer c = c2, this means c also has the value of 6 (?)

So, int tal = 6 + 5 which is 11.

It's not though. When I run it, it's 12.

Why does the `++tal` in the method `andra` affect its value globally? I thought it was only local.

I hope I haven't been to unclear.

The customer class is needed to run the test class.

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private int nbrOf;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getNbrOf() {
        return this.nbrOf;
    }

    public void setNbrOf (int nbrOf) {
        this.nbrOf=nbrOf;
    }

}
```

The first test class.

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Customer c = new Customer();
         c.setName("Kund1");
         c.setNbrOf(4+1);

         int tal = c.getNbrOf()+10;

         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c.getNbrOf());
         foo(c, tal+3);
         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c.getNbrOf());
         System.out.println("Tal: "+tal);
    }

    public static void foo(Customer p, int x) {
        p.setName("Kund2");
        p.setNbrOf(x);
        x ++;
    }
}
```

The second.

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Customer c = new Customer();
         c.setName("K1");

         Customer c2 = c;
         c.setNbrOf(4+1);
         c2.setNbrOf(c.getNbrOf()+1);
         int tal = c.getNbrOf()+5;
         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c2.getNbrOf());
         andra(c, ++tal);
         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c.getNbrOf()+", 
         "Tal: "+tal);
    }
    public static void andra(Customer p, int tal) {
         p.setName("K2");
         tal=9;
         p.setNbrOf(tal);
    }
}
```

Comment: `tal=9; p.setNbrOf(tal);` so it's always 9?

Comment: Why does your `andra` method accept a value for `tal` and then ignore it?

Comment: c2 holds the same object as c, there has no second `new Customer()` been called. That should explain all. _By the way, as question this is terrible: it starts in the middle with still undefined things._

Comment: *"It's not though. When I run it, it's 12. "* ... obviously because the program doesn't ignore the `++tal` like you did in your calculation.

Comment: `andra(c2,++tal)`  takes  a customer and an `tal` and just right before to call it, it increments its value by one, going from `11` to `12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] Fixed the incorrect part about pass by value and `clone()`

You are asking two questions so let's attach each one separately.

A) What is the value of `c` and `c2` at specific points in the code.

To answer this you need to realize that just saying 'c = c2' doesn't tell the full story.  You first create two instances of the Customer object and store the references to them in `c` and `c2` respectively.  When you assign `c = c2` you are making both variable store the reference to the same (single) instance of Customer; the other will get garbage collected.  Now, it is possible to change the state of the remaining object through method calls to either `c` OR `c2` because they both refer to the same instance.

This means that

```
c.setNbrOf(4+1);               // AAA
c2.setNbrOf(c.getNbrOf()+1);   // BBB
```

changes the value of the same nbrOf member variable twice, it just looks like they are separate because you have made `c` an alias of `c2` (or vice versa depending on how you want to look at it). After line AAA `c.nbrOf` does equal 5; to calculate what happens in line BBB you need to break the line up into its parts.  Calling `c2.setNbrOf()` with an argument that is actually an expression of the sum of two things, the result of a call to `c.getNbrOf()` and the numeric literal '1'.  The call to `c.getNbrOf()` returns 5 and the expression adds 1 to it before passing the result, 6, to the call of `c2.setNbrOf()`.  Since `c` and `c2` are aliases of each other you will get a result of '6' when you call `getNbrOf` using either `c` or `c2` simply because they both point to the same instance.

B) Why does the ++tal in the method andra affect it's value globally?

Well, it doesn't affect the value globally, it only looks that way because again, you have run into an expression used as an argument to a method.

```
andra(c, ++tal);      // CCC
```

The call to `andra()` does not pass '++tal' into the method, it evaluates the expression first, which actually increments tal by 1 in the local scope and then evaluates the value of `tal` to determine the value to be sent to the method call.  This means that, yes, `tal` was 11 before the line CCC but during the evaluation of the arguments the variable's value was changed to 12 before the call is made.  So why does the code print '12' when you can clearly see that

```
public static void andra(Customer p, int tal) {
         p.setName("K2");
         tal=9;            // DDD
         p.setNbrOf(tal);
    }
```

line DDD should result in the value of p.nbrOf being 9?  Well, yes, the value of p.nbrOf does get changed to '9' in the line following DDD, just as p.name gets changed to "K2".  This leads to your question of why the code prints '12' instead of '9'. This is because of another thing you have to consider and that is scope.  The method `andra()` actually creates a new storage location named 'tal' that is not the same location as the variable with the same name in `main()`, that is `andra()` is hiding the name 'tal' so that when it changes the value of 'tal' to 9 it is only changing the local variable and not the variable with the same name in the calling code.

I have to say that this sample code is doing several things to trip you up, which also means it's doing its job to help you understand the different ways the language handles its symbol table that can be confusing. The sample code isn't making it any better by using `tal` as a local variable in the test code AND as a parameter name in the methods, that is a poor practice but was used here to make the exercise more difficult.

Try this code to see what is actually happening.

```
// actually Test3 would be a better name, but I'll leave that to you
public class Test {   
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Customer c = new Customer();
         c.setName("K1");

         Customer c2 = c;
         c.setNbrOf(4+1);
         c2.setNbrOf(c.getNbrOf()+1);
         int tal = c.getNbrOf()+5;
         int tal2 = ++tal;
         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c2.getNbrOf()+" reference to c:"+ c);
         andra(c, tal2);
         System.out.println("Namn: "+c.getName()+" ålder: "+c.getNbrOf()+", 
         Tal: "+tal);
    }
    public static void andra(Customer p, int tal3) {
         p.setName("K2");
         tal3=9;
         System.out.println("BEFORE - reference to p: "+p+" tal: "+tal3+" p.nbrOf:"+p.getNbrOf());
         p.setNbrOf(tal3);
         System.out.println("AFTER - reference to p: "+p+" tal: "+tal3+" p.nbrOf:"+p.getNbrOf());

    }
}
```

This should show several things, the reference to `p` should be a different value than the reference held in `c`, using unique variable and parameter names should make it clearer about which variables are being evaluated or changed, and  moving the `++tal` expression to outside the method call should show how the variable is not being changed from within `andra()`.

Comment: There is some wrong information in this answer. Java does not implicitly copy objects, and it definitely doesn't implicitly call `clone()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `++tal`, it means `tal = tal + 1;` then return the new value of `tal` as a result. Hence, when you pass `++tal` to a function, you have run two commands.

Also, you should be aware that setting value of `tal` inside `andra` function, is local and not changed the value of `tal` outside the function. Hence, the final value of `tal` after calling `andra(c, ++tal)` would be `12`.

Answer (score 0):

`c = c2` - this line means that from now you want `c` to point to the same space in memory that holds `c2`. From now all changes in `c` or `c2` will affect in the same change in the value of the other one (two different refferences point to the same object)

Answer (score 0):

```
andra(c, ++tal);
```

is:

```
tal = tal + 1; //12
andra(c, tal);
```

Answer (score 0):

`andra(c, ++tal);` is the same as:

```
tal = tal + 1;
andra(c, tal);
```

While `andra(c, tal++);` is similar to:

```
andra(c, tal);
tal = tal + 1;
```

The pre-increment and post-increment operators increment the value prior to (pre) or after (post) evaluating the expression. This is not a "local" vs "global" scope. It affects the scope of the variable that is within scope.

Also, in your andra method, you are explicitly setting `tal = 9` so it ignores the passed argument.

Answer (score 0):

since we actually only have one object here, we could ignore OO here and write it in plain math:
if c2 = c, then there is only one object, therefore only one `NbrOf`

```
     c.setNbrOf(4+1);
```

NbrOf = 4 + 1 = 5

```
     c2.setNbrOf(c.getNbrOf()+1);
```

NbrOf = NbrOf + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6

```
     int tal = c.getNbrOf()+5;
```

int tal = NbrOf + 5 = 6 + 5 = 11;

```
     andra(c, ++tal);
```

this increases tal by 1 and assigns that value to tal, its equivalent to

```
      tal = tal + 1;
      andra(c, tal);
```

however, the tal inside of `andra(c, tal);` is an *copied value* (all primitives are passed by copy, not by reference. So assigning tal=9 wont affect the outside tal! Rename it inside `andra(c, tal);` to make it easier to understand.

**conclusion, tal = 12**